# Best object detection model where inference speed is not a factor?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition, object-detection

As in the question I’m wondering what is the current best model for object detection in images where inference time doesn’t matter?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried yolo v5  or RCNN? Also object detection models are offered by cloud services. If you don't have sensitive data, may be use those?

Comment: Hi Soumya, that

Comment: Hi Soumya, thanks for the suggestion. I need something where accuracy is important and inference speed doesn’t need to be optimised. Both of those models seem to be optimising for speed or FPS. From what I have researched EfficientDet D7x seems to be the most accurate. But I’m no expert in this area.

Comment: Oh okay, i suggested yolo v5 because it was quite new and rcnn because i have had good results in net. I didn't realize efficientnet had a variant for detection. Must be sota then! There must be a sota benchmark for detection right?